# Can Confluence be used as a Yammer or Facebook replacement?

Tags: confluence, yammer

We are evaluating Confluence as a wiki and the foundation for a company intranet.  We have previously used Yammer, with it's Facebook like social activity stream (post a thought, a link, a photo, and other users can comment or 'like' the post).

Does Confluence have a feature or plugin that offers this sort of functionality?  To be clear, I do not want a widget that will display content pulled from Yammer or Facebook - we just want similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confluence has some facebook-like social features which where introduced in the latest versions (especially in 4.x) for better collaboration.

These includes:

- [User Status Updates](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/User+Status+Updates)
- [@mentions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Mentions)
- [Likes and Popular Content](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Likes+and+Popular+Content)
- [Commenting on Pages and Blog posts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Commenting+on+pages+and+blog+posts)

**My opinion**:
I have seen Confluence in many companies as a intranet platform with good acceptance. But you should be aware that it is mainly a enterprise wiki and usabilty is focused on this.
Posting a photo for example is only possible when creating a blog-post.
Where as you can post a thought by using your personal status update.

Also see

- [Network Overview](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Network+Overview)
- http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/09/confluence_4_social_content_collaboration/

Comment: Jimmy, thanks for your reply.  I was thinking about it this morning, and I might create a company wide "blog" that anyone can post to.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, as of August 2015, there are some plugins published to Marketplace which implement this functionality. One of those I've seen is Blue.

Comment: A screenshot or link would be more helpful.

Comment: @serenesat There was no request for screenshots in the original post. However you may find lots of screenshots via the link: http://bfy.tw/1jwc.

Comment: I know there was no request for screenshot, but your answer will be more real and it will be more helpful for future readers.

Comment: @serensat does it mean the answer should be downvoted?..

Comment: I didn't downvote.